# almacenar mas de una variable de un ciclo for en diccionarios

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
productos = []
mercaderias = int(input("introduce la cantidad de items en tu carrito: "))
for items in range(mercaderias): 
  codigo = int(input("introduce el codigo de tu producto: "))
  peso = float(input("introduce el peso en kilos de tu producto: "))
  productos.append(codigo)
  productos.append(peso) 
print(productos)
```

que me arroja un resultado de este tipo:

```
introduce la cantidad de items en tu carrito: 3
introduce el codigo de tu producto: 1
introduce el peso en kilos de tu producto: 1.5
introduce el codigo de tu producto: 2
introduce el peso en kilos de tu producto: 3
introduce el codigo de tu producto: 1
introduce el peso en kilos de tu producto: 1.8
[1, 1.5, 2, 3.0, 1, 1.8]
```

Necesito saber como puedo almacenar/separar/manipular los datos obtenidos en la lista productos.
En este caso, necesito que el 1° y 2° numero se almacenen en una misma variable, que despues yo pueda manipular.
Lo mismo con el 3° y 4° elemento y con el 5° y 6°. Esto depende de cuantos productos se ingresen, lo cual depende del range del ciclo for, que es un input.

Lo mejor seria hacer un diccionario? como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: un diccionario... o una clase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes almacenar la informacion del producto en un diccionario. Al final tendras una lista de diccionarios.

```
productos = []
mercaderias = int(input("introduce la cantidad de items en tu carrito: "))

for items in range(mercaderias):
    producto = {}
    producto['codigo'] = int(input("introduce el codigo de tu producto: "))
    producto['peso'] = float(input("introduce el peso en kilos de tu producto: "))
    productos.append(producto)

print(productos)

# introduce la cantidad de items en tu carrito: 1
# introduce el codigo de tu producto: 123
# introduce el peso en kilos de tu producto: 7.5
# [{'codigo': 123, 'peso': 7.5}]
```

Comment: Genial, me encanta esa solución! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Si te ayuda mi respuesta marcala como respuesta correcta

Comment: como puedo hacer una vez que se crean estos diccionarios para acceder a las llaves y valores de cada uno de ellos?

Comment: como mencioné tienes una lista de diccionarios, quiere decir que cada elemento de la lista es un diccionario. Por ejemplo si quieres el primer producto harias algo como esto: `producto1 = productos[0]` y para obtener los valores solo debes poner el nombre de la llave del diccionario. `producto1['codigo']` para obtener el codigo. [informacion de diccionarios](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Comment: No sé qué tan buena idea sea usar una lista de diccionarios que solo almacenarán 2 elementos. ¿Por qué mejor no usar una lista de tuplas o listas?

Comment: Creo es cuestion de gustos. No veo ningun impacto en rendimiento. A diferencia de las listas y tuplas, los diccionarios son mas explicitos sobre que esta alamacenado al usar las llaves como si fueran identificadores. Tambien te facilita el acceso a los datos sin tener que utilizar indices como en las listas

Comment: la pregunta lo pide en diccionarios...

Comment: No realmente. Solo pregunta si sería mejor hacerlo con diccionarios.